# How to verify that a trigger does not touch anything ( Unity 2D )

Tags: unity-game-engine

An object has a trigger and its purpose, when an object is present, performed an action, and if there are no objects, another action

OnTrigger does not work, as it works on contact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subscribe to the following *messages*:

- [**OnTriggerEnter**](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html): OnTriggerEnter is called when the Collider other
  enters the trigger.
- [**OnTriggerExit**](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerExit.html): OnTriggerExit is called when the
  Collider other has stopped touching the trigger.

---

Proceed as follows:

1. From `OnTriggerEnter`, add the object that entered to a list(*)
2. From `OnTriggerExit`, remove the object that left from that list.

Then at any time, the list will contain every element that's inside the trigger.

3. From `Update`, do your action depending on whether the list is empty or not.

*Note: I'm using the term « list » as in « collection of your choice ». It makes sense to use a `HashSet<>` rather than a `List<>` if the trigger can overlap with a significant number of objects.*

---

*EDIT:* I see your question mentions "Unity 2D". If that means you just need 2D collisions, consider using [`Collider2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.html)s, and its 2D counterparts to the aforementioned hooks [`OnTriggerEnter2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.OnTriggerEnter2D.html) and [`OnTriggerExit2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.OnTriggerExit2D.html)